# Generate multiple polygons based on JPEG image?

Tags: digital-image-processing, vectorization

[image]

I have a number of image files depicting polygons (the original shapefiles are lost). Is there a way to automatically create new polygons in GIS, based on the form of the shapes visible in the image? 
Ideally this would include distinguishing bettween different colours, e.g. by adding information to the attribute table for each color category.

Comment: What GIS software are you using? QGIS? ArcGIS? Other?

Comment: I have both QGIS and ArcGIS and basic to intermediate skills in it.